# Proof for a non strictly increasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

In this exercise, I have the sequence $a_n = \lfloor \frac{n}{6}\rfloor$ and I have to prove that it's increasing but not strictly increasing.

I actually got stuck because I haven't been taught the difference between increasing and strictly increasing. I tried to search around, but tell me if I'm right: if $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$ then it's increasing. If $a_{n+1} > a_n$ then it's strictly increasing.

Right?

Anyway, about the proof I thought this:

$$a_{n+1} > a_n \implies \lfloor \frac{n+1}{6}\rfloor > \lfloor \frac{n}{6}\rfloor$$
Hence

$$\lfloor \frac{n}{6}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{1}{6}\rfloor > \lfloor\frac{n}{6}\rfloor$$

But $\lfloor \frac{1}{6}\rfloor = 0$, hence $a_{n+1}$ is actually equals to $a_n$, hence we need $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$, so the sequence is not strictly increasing, but it's increasing.

Can you please tell me if this could work, or if I need more things / details?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to think that if $a_{n+1}\geqslant a_n$ then $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is increasing and if $a_{n+1}>a_n$ then $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is strictly increasing. Actually, this simply doesn't make sense, since you don't say what $n$ is. Asserting that $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is increasing means that *for each natural $n$* you have $a_{n+1}\geqslant a_n$ , and asserting that $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is strictly increasing means that *for each natural $n$* you have $a_{n+1}>a_n$.

Your sequence is increasing because, for each natural $n$,\begin{align}\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}6\right\rfloor&=\left\lfloor\frac n6+\frac16\right\rfloor\\&\geqslant\left\lfloor\frac n6\right\rfloor.\end{align}And it is not strictly increasing because, for instance, $\left\lfloor\frac26\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac16\right\rfloor$.

On the other hand, it is *false* in general that $\left\lfloor\frac n6+\frac16\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac n6\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac16\right\rfloor$.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to specify what $n$ is and that $a_n: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ too. Thank you!!
I didn't know that the floor function is not linear in the sum, I just run some thoughts... Again thanks!

Comment: So to prove that it's not strictly increasing, I just had to show an example? There is no other analytical general proof?

Comment: Since asserting that a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is strictly increasing means that, for *each* $n\in\Bbb N$, $a_{n+1}>a_n$, asserting that it is *not* strictly increasing means that, for *some* $n\in\Bbb N$, $a_{n+1}\leqslant a_n$. So, yes, you test some $n$'s until you find one that works. It's the most natural approach.